# Неправильно работает копирование/вставка данных

Tags: excel

Через функцию ВПР взяты данные. Но копировать и вставить их значения в ексель файл не получается. Вот что выходит:

[image]

справа данные, которые я скопировал и вставил в левую часть, но удачно скопировано только первое число, а дальше какие-то другие числа, и я копировал весь столбец справа, а вставлено только 7 чисел.
Когда выделяю ячейки для копирования, то выходит так как на картинке снизу[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мало данных для анализа. Вариаты: скрыты строки; данные вставляются не как значения (заголовок - копирование ячеек, в вопросе - копирование значений...). Если не то, найдите возможность показать проблемный файл.

Comment: Я вставлял как значения. Если же вырезать и вставить, то весь столбец попадает под формулу и портится, но вставляется верно. А когда пробую копировать, то выходит как на картинке. Каждая ячейка выделена отдельно, может из-за этого??

Comment: *Каждая ячейка выделена отдельно*  - скрытые строки в диапазоне.

Comment: как это можно исправить?

Comment: Отобразить строки. У Вас происходит копирование только видимых значений.  Копированные значения вставляются все, но Вы их не все видите (в диапазоне вставки тоже скрыты строки).

Comment: спасибо, так и есть. У меня стояли фильтры и скрытые строки. Все получилось.

Comment: Внимательнее... О скрытых строках - сразу, в первом комментарии